# Stuck on login screen - unable to login, unable to show console

Tags: login

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS and everything was working fine until yesterday. Now I cannot login, I have some crappy resolution (600x400?) and everytime I try to login (I am 100% sure I have the password right) it simply goes back to login screen. Logging in as guest (no password) does the same.

I cannot show the console: every time I press Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3 the screen just goes black and reboots this computer.

I would appreciate ALL help, please! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try to select an option other than default from the grub menu. Press and hold  Shift (sometimes ESC works) to access grub menu if it does not show up automatically.